# How do I add a <a> element with a href attribut in multiple <li> element?

Tags: javascript

I have a task that is to create links on navigation list's "li" elements and its text. So I have to add a anchor element with a href attribut to three li elements with class="navigation".  I tried to do a code to this, but it's not correct can anyone help me to make it work.

```
var a = document.createElement("a");
var li = document.getElementsByClassName("navigation");
for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
a.setAttribute("href", "#html");
li.appendChild(a);
}
```

li class = "navigation" - should be changed to be - 
li class = "navigation" a href="#HTML"  and so on for the three "li" elements.

Answer (score 3):

In you code `a` is declared only once and when when you change `setAttribute` and append `a` to `li` `a` will refer to the same element.

- Move the declaration of `a` inside the for loop.
- Use `li[i]` instead of `li` because `li` is not element its HTMLCollection.

Also add some innerHTML to `a` so see if its present.And avoid declaring implicit globals. Use `let` with `i`.

```
var li = document.getElementsByClassName("navigation");
for (let i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
   var a = document.createElement("a");
   a.setAttribute("href", "#html");
   a.innerHTML = 'link' + i
   li[i].appendChild(a);
}
```

I would suggest you using `querySelectorAll` and `forEach` loop.

```
var li = document.querySelectorAll(".navigation");
li.forEach(x => {
  var a = document.createElement("a");
  a.setAttribute("href", "#html");
  a.innerHTML = 'link' + i
  x.appendChild(a);

})
```

Comment: @MattEllen Thanks for suggestion. I have edited the answer.

Comment: There is a typo in the first code, 
`for (let i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {` `a.length` should be `li.length`

Comment: Great code, this worked. Thank you!  But now I have another problem. The navigation is not a link but instead there is a link next to the navigation headline.

Comment: @Sus Can't say anything without seeing the code you are using.

Comment: The HTML code is             
                <li class="navigation">HTML</li>
                <li class="navigation">DOM</li>
                <li class="navigation">Javascript</li>
And the result on the page is - HTMLlink0 DOMlink1 Javasscriptlink2

Comment: @Sus If you want to remove `HTML,...` then use `li[i].innerHTML = ''` in the start of loop.